# Unable to login to wordpress with selenium wrapper because cookies are blocked?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, cookies

I'm running an automated test on my `wordpress` website using selenium wrapper (through VBA).

When the login button is clicked, I get this error:

```
ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser
```

[image]

I've changed the settings in IE to accept all cookies. Chrome does accept cookies by default but for some reason, this doesn't seem to work. Could it be the user agent?

My wordpress version is 4.5

```
'Login code 
Sub InitiateLogin()

    web_driver.get "wp-login", -1, False
    web_driver.findElementById(Base64DecodeString("STUFFHERE")).SendKeys Base64DecodeString("STUFFHERE")
    web_driver.findElementById(Base64DecodeString("STUFFHERE")).SendKeys Base64DecodeString("STUFFHERE")
    web_driver.findElementById("wp-submit").Click
    web_driver.setTimeout ("120000")
    web_driver.setImplicitWait (5000)
   End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest doing it like [HERE](https://advanceddataanalytics.net/2015/03/30/sending-an-xml-rpc-message-from-vba-e-g-excel-to-wordpress/) or [HERE](https://advanceddataanalytics.net/2015/04/02/vba-wordpress-connection-class-with-first-connection-test/) doesn't work either?

Comment: Can you show your code for the setup for web_driver?

Comment: selenium wrapper for vba 1.something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is only more up to date that the accepted answer.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Login()
    Dim driver As ChromeDriver
    Set driver = New ChromeDriver
    ' this works using either edge or Chrome
    Call driver.Start("edge", "https://wordpress.com/")
'    Call driver.Start("Chrome", "https://wordpress.com/")
    driver.get ("/wp-login.php")
    driver.Window.Maximize
    sbDelay (100000)
    driver.FindElementByClass("cookie-banner__accept-all-button").Click
    sbDelay (100000)
    driver.FindElementById("usernameOrEmail").Clear
    driver.FindElementById("usernameOrEmail").SendKeys "your username or email"
    sbDelay (100000)
    driver.FindElementByClass("button").Click 'Continue
    sbDelay (100000)
    driver.FindElementById("password").Clear
    driver.FindElementById("password").SendKeys "your password"
    sbDelay (100000)
    driver.FindElementByClass("button").Click 'Continue
    sbDelay (1000000)
    driver.Quit
End Sub

Sub sbDelay(delay As Long): Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To delay:  DoEvents: Next i: End Sub 'old skool delay
```

I used the VBA type library that Microsoft support

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

I used MS Edge - the Selenium version must match the version of edge that you have installed.

Edge Version 110.0.1587.57

You will need to browse to the type library for your machine either 32 or 64 bit.

Tools > References > Selenium Type Library (Selenium64.tlb)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to login to the account without issues using the below code.

```
Private driver As SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver

Private Sub Login()
    Set driver = New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
    Call driver.Start("chrome", "https://wordpress.com/")

    driver.get ("/wp-login.php")
    driver.findElementById("user_login").Clear
    driver.findElementById("user_login").SendKeys "your userid here"
    driver.findElementById("user_pass").Clear
    driver.findElementById("user_pass").SendKeys "your password here"
    driver.findElementById("wp-submit").Click
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you give more info please? How this does not help and also, if possible add a reproducebal example of your issue!

Comment: I'll im kinda of busy right now. i will award you the bounty anyways thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I fixed mine by redirecting the page to the form's `action` value. Using Python my code was:

```
...

form = driver.find_element_by_id('loginform')
form_post_url = form.get_attribute('action')

# login_url is the current URL
if login_url != form_post_url:
    driver.get(form_post_url)

form = driver.find_element_by_id('loginform')

# Do login
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't realise there was a redirect, I simply logged in via the redirected page rather than using your code but knowing it was there was helpful.

Comment: Made this the accepted answer.